# NCMPCPP Backend For Windows (or how to setup MPD on Windows)?

Tags: windows-7, kubuntu, mpd

I run Kubuntu(x64)+tmux at work and a Windows 7 x64 machine at home. I would really like to run ncmpcpp at work in a tmux window that connects to my Windows machine at home.  I can port forward and I have a DynDNS account that is also set up on my router.  My only problem is getting MPD (or something analogous) running in a server role on my Windows 7 machine at home.  So my question(s) are as follows:

- Is there an ncmpcpp backend that was designed for, or runs well on, Windows (7)?
- If not, is there a good, recent guide for getting mpd running on Windows 7?

  - I have looked at their site.  They don't even attempt to properly document the windows release.  Understandable, but just not any help.  I have also found a rather complicated guide utilizing Cygwin but I'd rather not go through all that if I don't have to.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I assume you're sshing to the windows 7 machine, or something similar? If so, you're not going to get audio over that by default.

Comment: @Rob No I am not planning to SSH into the machine.  I am planning on using NCMPCPP as a remote client pointed at my Windows 7 machine running an MPD server.

Comment: Ahh, that makes much more sense. :D

Answer (score 3):

You may be past this already, but I'll document what I did in getting MPD set up on Windows 7.  This will probably be overkill if you've ever used mpd before, but since I hadn't, this is what I would have found helpful:

1. Download / unzip the windows binaries (I'm using [`mpd-0.16.6-4-win32`](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Server) and [`mpc-0.21-win32`](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Client:Mpc))
2. Edit mpd.conf  - here's a sample (with the comments removed):

   ```
   music_directory     "d:/music"
   playlist_directory      "d:/music/mpd/playlists"
   db_file         "d:/music/mpd/database"
   log_file            "d:/music/mpd/log"
   port                "6600"
   auto_update "yes"
   input {
           plugin "curl"
   }

   audio_output {
     type "winmm"
     name "Default"
   }
   ```

   Note that `d:\music` and `d:\music\mpd` and `d:\music\mpd\playlists` must exist.
3. Start the mpd server by running from the command line: `mpd mpd.conf`.  Note that you apprently have to specify the configuration file, or it won't work.  It will probably complain about the database not being found, but will go ahead and create a new one.
4. Use mpc to check if it's working:

   - `mpc listall` to get a list of all the files scanned by MPD
   - `mpc add <file>` to add a file to the current playlist (use the same path output by `mpc listall`)
   - `mpc play` to start playing
   - Use `ctrl-c` on the mpd console to stop it.
5. If that all works, you can get mpc to start on computer startup using scheduled tasks, so you don't need to log in for it to run:

   - Start `task scheduler` (just type it in the Windows start search bar)
   - Create a task
   - Set `Run whether the user is logged on or not`
   - Add a trigger.  Begin the task at startup.  Add a delay if you want.
   - Add an action.  Program/script = "mpd", add arguments: "mpd.conf", start in "c:\program files..." (wherever you extracted mpd.exe to).
   - Close and save the task, and supply credentials for it to run under.
   - You can run the action now and mpd will load up in the background, and again every time you boot up your computer.

   You won't see it in Task Manager, unless you click "Show processes from all users" even if it's running under your username.
6. Install IIS (or some other webserver), using `Turn windows features on or off`, make sure to include CGI under IIS > WWW Services > App Development Features.
7. Install [PHP](http://php.iis.net/).
8. Download [phpMpReloaded](http://phpmpreloaded.sourceforge.net/), and point IIS at it.
9. Open up port 80 on your windows firewall.

Obviously different clients / webservers can be used, but this is roughly what I have running.  Combined with a set of wireless speakers, this lets me run music through the whole house, controllable by any device with access to my WIFI network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't want a web interface on my MPD, I want to use it as a server for a remote client (like NCMPCPP or wtfever that long acronym is).  BUT I think your steps will get me to the point where I can accomplish that!  I will try it and get back to you.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Eric: If you're wanting to listen to music on a remote computer, you'll also have to figure out how to use a different output plugin.  The winmm plugin just plays to one of windows audio devices.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'll have to do some further research on that.